# Android Emulator: "current state doesn't support snapshotting"

Tags: android

I am trying to save a snapshot of a running Android (14) Emulator, but more often than not I get this cryptic error:

```
current state doesn't support snapshotting
```

I cannot find this documented anywhere, what exactly are the rules for being allowed to create a snapshot?